# GCM Statistics data not updating day over day

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-console-developer

Within the Google Play Developer console, I am using the Statistics section to get information about how my Push notifications are performing.

In the statistics section, when I select GCM Messages and I look at the GCM MESSAGES BY GCM MESSAGE STATUS graph, the numbers do not seem to change day over day..
i.e. the number of stored and delivered are constant. Isn't GCM supposed to re-try for upto 4 weeks for delivery of push notifications? If that is the case, isn't the count for stored and delivered supposed to changes for the past few days as GCM try's to deliver for upto 4 weeks.

so why doesn't my graph numbers change day over day to account for additional deliveries made from GCM in the 4 week window...

I am sending over a million push notifications with about 50% showing as stored and only 50% delivered.

Any insight into how GCM statistics works i.e. is it only a snapshot of the first day or is there a way to show delivery status day over day...

Thanks!!

Comment: According to here:https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en.  You can sign up for GCM for both Play and non-Play apps. However, GCM statisticss will be available for only `published` Google Play apps.